# Превращение столбца таблицы DataGrid в DataGridComboBoxColumn без отвязки от DataTable в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Здравствуйте. Есть таблица с данными:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add();
dt.Columns.Add();
dt.Rows.Add("111", "test1");
dt.Rows.Add("222", "test2");
dt.Rows.Add("333", "test3");
dt.Rows.Add("444", "test4");
DG.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;
```

А также есть список строк:

```
List<string> Source = new List<string>() { "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4" };
```

Таблица привязана к DataGrid.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DG" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="348" Width="569" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы второй столбец таблицы отображался в виде `ComboBox`, источником которого является лист `Source`, но при этом любое изменение должно заносится обратно в `DataTable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пусть у нас имеется две колонки Name и Test.

Имеется два варианта. В коде:

```
List<string> Source = new List<string>() { "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4" };
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

DataColumn d1 = new DataColumn("Name");
DataColumn d2 = new DataColumn("Test");
dt.Columns.Add(d1);
dt.Columns.Add(d2);
dt.Rows.Add("111", "test1");
dt.Rows.Add("222", "test2");
dt.Rows.Add("333", "test3");
dt.Rows.Add("444", "test4");

DataGridTextColumn colText = new DataGridTextColumn();
colText.Header = "Name";
colText.Binding = new Binding("Name");

DataGridComboBoxColumn colCombo = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
colCombo.Header = "Test";
colCombo.SelectedItemBinding = new Binding("Test");
colCombo.ItemsSource = Source;

DG.Columns.Add(colText);
DG.Columns.Add(colCombo);
DG.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;
```

И нужно в DG приравнять свойство AutoGenerateColumns = false;

Но лучше это сделать в xaml, описав там все колонки и привязки:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DG"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Test" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Test}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static s:MainWindow.Source}}" ></DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>            
</DataGrid>
```

В данном случае я сделал Source (неудобное название вы выбрали) статическим полем формы MainWindow, если вам нужна другая привязка поменяйте ее.